# Some Greek characters are not displayed with chemgreek + fontspec + TeX Gyre fonts

Tags: fonts, xetex, luatex, greek, chemmacros

Some Greek characters are not printed with `chemgreek` package when I use TeX Gyre fonts.

Test code:

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\termes{texgyretermes-regular.otf}
\newfontfamily\schola{texgyreschola-regular.otf}
\newfontfamily\libertine{LinLibertine_R.otf}

\usepackage{chemgreek}
\selectchemgreekmapping{fontspec}

\begin{document}
{\termes Termes: \printchemgreekalphabet}
{\schola Schola: \printchemgreekalphabet}
{\libertine Linux Libertine: \printchemgreekalphabet}
\end{document}
```

The result with LuaTeX:
[image: The chemgreek + TeX Gyre test result with LuaTeX]

The result with XeTeX:
[image: The chemgreek + TeX Gyre test result with XeTeX]

The results looks slightly different between engines, but the both lack gamma, epsilon, iota and phi with all but Linux Libertine.

I have found [an answer mentioning the lack of complete Greek support in TeX Gyre](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/268396/118783) but I confirmed that these fonts contain "basic" Greek characters above.

Can I use `chemgreek` and TeX Gyre without missing characters?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The `chemgreek` package apparently assumes that `\textphi` maps to a Greek letter, but `xunicode` defines it as U+0278 LATIN SMALL LETTER PHI (it's thought for IPA). Not the only wrong case.

Comment: This will be fixed in `chemgreek` v1.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Update

> This behaviour is due to issues in `chemgreek` which are fixed
>   in the 1.1 (2016/12/20) release. Where possible, you should [update your TeX
>   distribution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437) to install the
>   current release. If this is not possible, for example if you want to
>   change only this one package or where you do not have the privileges
>   to update the entire distribution, you will need to [install the
>   package locally](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1137).  This option should be considered a last resort, since for more complex packages there may be package dependencies that will make local installation more complicated and error-prone.

---

## Original answer

The `chemgreek` package makes a few wrong assumptions: it assumes that `\textgamma`, `\textepsilon`, `\textiota` and `\textphi` map to the Greek characters, but they don't, as `xunicode.sty` defines them to be IPA characters (Latin small letter gamma, epsilon, iota and phi, respectively).

You can fix this, at least as far as `chemgreek` is concerned, by remapping the wrong targets:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\termes{texgyretermes-regular.otf}
\newfontfamily\schola{texgyreschola-regular.otf}
\newfontfamily\libertine{LinLibertine_R.otf}
\newfontfamily\tempora{Tempora}

\RenewDocumentCommand{\textgamma}{}{\symbol{"03B3}}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\textepsilon}{}{\symbol{"03B5}}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\textiota}{}{\symbol{"03B9}}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\textphi}{}{\symbol{"03C6}}

\usepackage{chemgreek}
\selectchemgreekmapping{fontspec}

\begin{document}

{\termes Termes: \printchemgreekalphabet}

{\tempora Tempora: \printchemgreekalphabet}

{\schola Schola: \printchemgreekalphabet}

{\libertine Linux Libertine: \printchemgreekalphabet}
\end{document}
```

I also added Tempora, but you can see that the coverage by TeX Gyre fonts is complete too.

[image]

By the way, `chemgreek` has a wrong alphabetical order, as it has chi after psi.

Comment: I wish I'd get bug reports in such cases. I don't always spot questions on tex.sx...

Comment: @clemens Opened https://github.com/cgnieder/chemgreek/issues/4 and https://github.com/cgnieder/chemgreek/issues/5

Comment: @clemens I'm sorry, I thought it was probably just my fault such as misunderstanding of setup options.

Comment: I've confirmed that the problem has been fixed on latest TL2016. Thank you @egreg and @clemens!